# Getting out of a for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

Edit: Problem fixed for the most part. The corrected code is below. For some reason, the CheckPwd function continues to return none if the user's input is 12 or more characters. This was the reason why the loop continued forever, so the elif was a nice fix.

Edit: Fixed the 12 or more char error too. Apparently the uppercase letters weren't being counted as letters, so the criteria for 'high' were not met, thus the output of none. So I adddd c+=u before check and everything is good now.

I'm trying to make a password strength checker program and for some reason, if the user's input is more than 11 characters long, the for loop (the first one in the CheckPwd function that goes through all the characters in string) will continue forever. Here is my code:

```
def CheckPwd(string):
    c = 0
    u = 0
    x = len(string)
    alph = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z')
    for s in string:
        for y in alph:
            if s == y:
                c += 1
            if s == y.upper():
                u += 1
c += u
if 4<=x<=7:
    g = 'low'
    return g
if 8<=x<=11 and 3<=c:
    g = 'med'
    return g
elif 12<=x<=15 and 5<=c and 2<=u:
    g = 'high'
    return g

print ('Welcome to Secure Password Checker! Here we will make sure your 4-15 character password is secure enough.')
usrpwd = input('Please enter your password: ')
while usrpwd==usrpwd:
    x = len(usrpwd)
    if 4<=x<=15:
        g = CheckPwd(usrpwd)
        if g == 'low':
            usrpwd = input('Password strength is too low, please enter a stronger one: ')
        if g == 'med':
            choice = input('Your password is ok, but it could use a little work. Would you like to enter a new one?(y/n): ')
            if choice == 'y':
                usrpwd = input('Please enter the new password: ')
            else:
                print('Here is your secure password: ' + usrpwd)
                break
        elif g == 'high':
            print('Congratulations! Your password is secure! Here is your password: ' + usrpwd)
            break
    else:
        usrpwd = input('Please enter a password that is 4-15 characters long: ')
```

I tried putting a break in the problem for loop (sc was the counter I was using for the break) :

```
for s in string:
    sc += 1
    if sc == x:
        break
    ...
```

This did not work for some reason. Maybe there is something I'm missing... If someone could help me end the problem for loop, that would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please indent well, this code as is won't run correctly

Comment: Sorry about that, could someone edit that, when I used the code format, the indentation on most of the functions and loops dissapeared.

Comment: Well, I edited the code. Be aware that the indentation was never the problem. Just a screw up when formating the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `for` loop, by definition, cannot produce an infinite loop.

The problem is in your `while` that will indeed continue forever if `g not in ['low', 'med', 'high']`.
This can be fixed using the `if g == 'low': ... elif ... elif ... else: raise ValueError`. construction instead.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem, i think. I also had a problem on the first if statement after the nested for loops and a problem in the 'med' choice responce (if you typed no, it would act as if you said yes) I'm going to edit the code to show what worked for me.